# Why don't antiparticles have antispin?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, antimatter

Antiparticles are often said to particles moving backwards in time. However if they are moving backwards in time shouldn't they also "spin backwards", meaning they should have negative or antispin? But as far as I know antiparticles have the same spin as particles. Why is that?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "antispin"? There are no negative spin numbers, and the CPT symmetry, which is the precise statement of "anti-particles are particles moving backward in time", does not touch the spin quantum number at all.

Comment: Spinning backwards changes $S_z\to-S_z$, but not $\boldsymbol S^2$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Wouldn't a change in P (=parity?) imply spinning backwards?

Comment: @asmaier: If you say that (but "spinning" has not really meaning for this because *there is nothing spinning here*), then your question dissolves itself because P maps states with a certain spin to state with the same spin.

Comment: the prefix **anti** is not exclusive to electric charges and may be used for other.  Observed antineutrinos have right-handed helicity ( then the same spin ), while neutrinos are left-handed.

Comment: this story of the positron going back in time is a calculus artefact, not to say a joke ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why, yes, they do!

Probably the most decisive way to show this involves "handedness" of neutrinos. I won't get too much into the details here, but neutrinos are nearly massless and travel at nearly the speed of light; and when something travels at the speed of light you can describe its spin as either "right-handed" (momentum and spin are in-line) or "left-handed" (momentum and spin are opposite). A crucial experiment was done I believe in the 60s where Europium absorbed an orbiting electron in reverse-beta-decay, growing into an unstable Strontium nucleus which then split apart emitting a photon; when the neutrino and photon are emitted back-to-back they must have opposite spins in order to preserve angular momentum, so we got to measure the neutrino's spin. This happened to prove that all neutrinos are left-handed, a big shock.

Because neutrinos are left-handed, antineutrinos are all right-handed. If there are right-handed neutrinos, or left-handed antineutrinos, then for some reason they don't seem to interact with normal matter anymore after that; we're not completely sure why, but neutrinos already were not very interacting particles to begin with, having no color charge for the strong nuclear force and no electromagnetic charge for the electromagnetic force.

However, we still say that an antineutrino is a spin-$\frac12$ particle. This is because its total spin is $S^2 = \hbar^2 \frac12 (\frac12 + 1)$, following the usual prescription of $\hbar^2 s (s + 1)$ for $s = \frac12$.This also means that $S_z = \pm \frac12 \hbar$ as anything larger than $\hbar/2$ or smaller than $-\hbar/2$ will not be able to stay within that bound for $S^2.$ In this way, we would not state that an antineutrino is a spin-$\frac{-1}{~~2}$ particle, that doesn't make any sense in the formula ($S^2$ would be negative?). It's just that the interactions that create an antineutrino will always generate the opposite spin from the corresponding time-reversed interaction where a neutrino is absorbed, and vice versa.

Prompted by @ACuriousMind below, I should also mention that after this experiment was done, results came from an awesome neutrino detector in Japan called "Super Kamiokande," which suggested strongly that neutrinos have "flavor oscillations" between electron-neutrinos, muon-neutrinos, and tau-neutrinos. The problem is that such flavor oscillations are only possible if the neutrino in fact *does* have mass, which breaks the above definition of "handedness:" helicity is not actually a Lorentz-invariant, since a reference frame which overtakes a left-handed neutrino sees it as a right-handed one, unless the particle is massless and therefore no reference frame can overtake it. So now the correct definition has to do with a more fundamental property called "chirality," which is the property of "this spin-$\frac12$ particle has a spinor wavefunction which flips by $-1$ under a 360-degree rotation; but which route around the complex plane does its spin follow in order to get from $1$ to $-1$ here?". See [this link](http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/06/19/helicity-chirality-mass-and-the-higgs/) for a touchy-feely explanation of these ideas.

Comment: Your explanation of X-handedness would be appropriate for massless particles (since then the projection of spin on momentum, the *helicity*, is an invariant), but in general, I believe you should be talking about *chirality* (which is *literally* handedness from Ancient Greek), which has no such intuitive characterization, but refers to certain types of representations. I'm leaving this rather nitpicky comment because the distinction between helicity and chirality is often not clearly made, and leads to ongoing confusion in many settings.

Comment: @ACuriousMind ok, added a little section exploding this idea a little bit. The problem with chirality, of course, is that you can't really easily explain it to a lay audience.

Comment: It's fine to not explain chirality, I just wanted to see *some* kind of mention that the helicity is not *actually* the thing we consider (since anyone a bit familiar with special relativity could think about going into a  frame where the momentum points the other way, thus making helicity ill-defined). (+1)